# Casting an object to an address returned by dlsym

Tags: c++, c

I am calling a function from shared object (a.so). I loaded a.so using dlopen and mapped function using dlsym.

```
    int (*funcPtr)() = reinterpret_cast<int(*)()>(dlsym(some symbol..));
```

My question is if my input variables for funcPtr contains an "this", how do i cast it then?

expected function

```
    int func(*this, int,int,int,int)
```

I am attempting to cast it as such

```
    class test
    {

    };

    int (*funcPtr)(*test, int,int,int,int) = reinterpret_cast<int(*)(*test,int,int,int,int)>(dlsym(some symbol..));
```

Comment: Pop quiz: how do you declare a pointer to the method of `this`'s class. You reinterpret_cast it using the same type that you would use to declare a pointer to a method of `this`'s class, that takes four ints as a parameter, and returns an int.

Comment: `*this` is not a type, so it can't appear as the type of a function parameter. What does the signature of this function you're trying to call look like?

Comment: How would it possibly contains a "this"?

Comment: You are casting an address to a pointer. Not what it says in your title, by a country mile.

Comment: my function is int myFunc(class *this, int a,int b,int c,int d). I am trying to cast this function via dlsym. Yet i am having some trouble trying to understand what will happen if i create a pseudo class and cast it.

Comment: Your function is not that, as functions don't take `this` as an argument. Trying to pretend that `this` is the first argument is going to land you squarely in undefined behavior territory.

Comment: @MichaelGoh well it would be `int (*funcPtr)(class *, int, int, int, int);`. Not sure why you think the name "this" has any relevance.

Comment: `int func(*this, int,int,int,int)` is not valid.

Comment: reinterpret_cast is entirely wrong here (and almost everywhere you see it). You want to convert the value not reinterpret the representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is if my input variables for funcPtr contains a [pointer to a class object], how do i cast it then?

In exactly the same way, except the argument list has the pointer in it:

```
void* addr = dlsym(some symbol..);
int (*funcPtr)(test*) = reinterpret_cast<int(*)(test*)>(addr);
```

Or a bit prettier with an alias:

```
using func = int(test*);
func* funcPtr = reinterpret_cast<func*>(addr);
```

In order to do this cast, the class must be declared. It does not need to be defined. You can declare a class like this:

```
class test;
```

Comment: So what u are trying to say, i will have to create my own class and cast it? what if i do not know the methods or variables from the class in the so?

Comment: No. You should not create your own class. A class doesn't need to be defined in order to do this cast. You do have to cast, since `dladdr` returns a void pointer.

Comment: so what you meant is if i would to declare a class "test" and i can use it in the argument list as such?
         'int (*funcPtr)(test*) = reinterpret_cast<int(*)(test*)>(addr);'

Comment: thanks a lot! thanks for providing advice instead of condescending remarks :)

Comment: @MichaelGoh There are no condescending remarks here. You should appreciate the advice given to you in the comments, and carefully think about answers to their questions.